# Can I define member function inside namespace in c# or outside a class?

Tags: c#

I mean is there any way to do it or is not possible to create a function of a class outside the class and I do know that by using struct, we can declare a function outside the class

Comment: no you can't...

Comment: Functions have to be inside classes, but you can split classes into separate files (called partial classes), but it's still the same class. Is there a different question that you're not asking?